# TDD of Sailsjs Waterline Models with Vowsjs

Tags: sails.js, vows, waterline

My problem is trying to do TDD of Waterline models. The tests I present are just boilerplate to get my suite constructed. Nevertheless, they raise valid issues. The primary problem is that I require the model in the Vows.js test. In the test scope the model is defined, but it does not have any properties inherited from the Waterline package. For example, here is some model code for "EducationLevel":

```
module.exports = {
  migrate: 'safe',
  tableName: 'education_levels',
  attributes: {
    id : { type: 'integer', required: true },
    description: { type: 'string', required: true },
    display_sort: { type: 'integer', required: true}
  }
};
```

And here are some trial tests:

```
vows = require('vows')
assert = require('assert')
EducationLevel = require('../api/models/EducationLevel')

vows.describe('tac_models').addBatch({
  'EducationLevel model' : {
    topic: function(){
      educationLevel = EducationLevel.create();
      return true;
    },
    'It exists': function (topic) {
      assert.equal(EducationLevel.create,undefined);
      assert.equal(EducationLevel.migrate,undefined);
    }
  }
}).export(module)
```

When I run the test, the first assertion passed, but the second does not:

```
 vows spec/*
 ✗  


    EducationLevel model 
      ✗ It exists 
        » expected undefined, 
    got  'safe' (==) // tac_models.js:13 
  ✗ Broken » 1 broken (1.545s)
```

This shows that the test knows only what is explicitly declared in the EducationLevel definition.  The 'migrate' property is defined because I explicitly define it in the code. It does not know about the Waterline method 'create'. How can I remedy this in a way that makes conventional TDD practical?